# Wrong indentation after ninth reference

Tags: indentation

I am using the IEEE template in Overleaf and it show a indentation after the ninth reference at the first line as demonstrated below

[image]

Here is the documentclass and packages that I exploited

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{caption2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{color}
```

Meanwhile, I wrote the references at the end of the manuscript as

```
\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{1}
S. Jin and S. Roy, “FMCW radar network: Multiple access and interference mitigation," \emph{IEEE J. Sel. Topics Signal Process.}, vol. 15, no. 4, pp. 968--979, Jun. 2021.


\bibitem{2}
C. H. Cox and E. I. Ackerman, “Review of radar system needs, and performance of techniques, for STAR," in \emph{Proc. IEEE Radar Conf.}, Mar. 2022.


\bibitem{3}
M. Heino, J. Marin, K. Hiltunen, and T. Riihonen, “On the prospects of in-band full-duplex radios as monostatic continuous-wave noise radars," in \emph{Proc. IEEE Radar Conf.}, Mar. 2022.

\bibitem{4}
A. Sabharwal, P. Schniter, D. Guo, D. W. Bliss, S. Rangarajan, and R. Wichman, “In-band full-duplex wireless: Challenges and opportunities," \emph{IEEE J. Sel. Areas Commun.}, vol. 32, no. 9, pp. 1637--1652, Sep. 2014.


\bibitem{5}
Y. Hua, “Advanced properties of full-duplex radio for securing wireless network," \emph{IEEE Trans. Signal Process.}, vol. 67, no. 1, pp. 120--135, Jan. 2019.

\bibitem{6}
A. Yadav, O. A. Dobre, and H. V. Poor, “Is self-interference in full-duplex communications a foe or a friend?," \emph{IEEE Signal Process. Lett.}, vol. 25, no. 7, pp. 951--955, Jul. 2018. 

\bibitem{7}
C. B. Barneto, S. D. Liyanaarachchi, M. Heino, T. Riihonen, and M. Valkama, “Full duplex radio/radar technology: The enabler for advanced joint communication and sensing," \emph{IEEE Wireless Commun.}, vol. 28, no. 1, pp. 82--88, Feb. 2021.

\bibitem{8}
K. V. Mishra, M. R. Bhavani Shankar, V. Koivunen, B. Ottersten, and S. A. Vorobyov, “Toward millimeter-wave joint radar communications: A signal processing perspective,” \emph{IEEE Signal Process. Mag.}, vol. 36, no. 5, pp. 100--114, Sep. 2019.

\bibitem{9}
J. A. Zhang \emph{et al.}, “An overview of signal processing techniques for joint communication and radar sensing," \emph{IEEE J. Sel. Topics Signal Process.}, vol. 15, no. 6, pp. 1295--1315, Nov. 2021.


\bibitem{10}
K. E. Kolodziej, J. P. Doane, B. T. Perry, and J. S. Herd, “Adaptive beamforming for multi-function in-band full-duplex applications," \emph{IEEE Wireless Commun.}, vol. 28, no. 1, pp. 28--35, Feb. 2021.

\bibitem{11}
A. Hovsepian, S. B. Venkatakrishnan, E. A. Alwan and J. L. Volakis, “Wideband beam steering using a 4-arm spiral array for simultaneous transmit and receive (STAR) operation," in \emph{Proc. IEEE Int. Symp. Antennas Propaga. USNC/URSI Nat. Radio Sci. Meet.}, 2018, pp. 1915--1916.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `\begin{thebibliography}{1}` to `\begin{thebibliography}{99}`.

The parameter after the `\begin{thebibliography}` command defines how much space to reserve for the number of labels. `{99}` tells LaTeX to expect that none of the bibliography item numbers will be wider than the number 99.

Comment: Really thanks! It works!

Comment: Hi, could you add to your answer a short explanation as to why this solves the problem? What does the second input do?

Comment: @EladDen the number in the environment argument is supposed to be the largest (in sense of width) number used in the list; it is used to calculate the amount of indentation.

Comment: @EladDen I have add explanation to answer.